# How can I find a partial string in a html table cell and append text to the value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm piping a .txt file that is generated from powershell for the health status of some hardware. this is piped into a html table and the data changes frequently so it is nearly impossible to assign id's or classes to the . Specifically one column of cells generates error messages that can be quite lengthy. I want to key in on the first couple of words from the text in that cell. It starts with "Error Message" (without quotes) how can I use my code to pick out that text and append it to add some CSS to make it easier for someone reading the report to quickly see there is an issue?

this is what I have thus far. Cant figure out this last little part.  I am also limited to JavaScript to solve this.

```
var td = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td'));
td.forEach(function(td) {
       if(td.innerHTML == 'Error') {
          td.innerHTML = "Error" + " " + '<button class="yellow_stoplight"></button>';}     
    if(td.innerHTML == 'Warning') {
           td.innerHTML = "Warning" + " " + '<button class="red_stoplight"></button>'; }
              if(td.innerHTML == 'Degraded') {
         td.innerHTML = "Degraded" + " " + '<button class="orange_stoplight"></button>'; }
          if(td.innerHTML == 'OK') {
             td.innerHTML = "OK" + " " + '<button class="green_stoplight"></button>'; } 
        if(td.innerHTML == 'Error' + " ") {
           td.innerHTML = "Error" + " " + '<button class="red_stoplight"></button>'; }  
\\want to add another conditional statement here to find partial string and add another 'stoplight' in the cell.



   });
```

######### EDIT

Adding the following not only gives me a visual indicator but maintains the full error message text that is piped into the column/cell.

```
if(td.innerHTML.indexOf('Error message') === 0) {
   td.innerHTML = '<button class="yellow_stoplight"></button>' + " " + td.innerHTML; }
```

Comment: Why not add the class directly to the `td` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`td.innerHTML` returns a string. Javascript strings have a `indexOf` method that you can use to find the location of a substring inside another string. It returns `-1` if the string doesn't contain the substring.

If you want to check if the inner HTML starts with "Error Message", try this:

```
if (td.innerHTML.indexOf("Error Message") === 0) {
  // do stuff..
}
```

Note that the indexOf method is case sensitive. If there's not "Error Message" in the innerHTML, it will return -1.

Comment: ^ above works partially. The css stoplight is being added immediately following "Error message" but the code is removing the rest of the error message details. Essentially I want to create a visual indicator for those reading the report so it is not skipped.

Comment: I want to upvote this because it solves my issue 99%. Need to figure out how to keep the entire message text and add the stoplight for visual indicator.

Comment: Solved my issue and it was rather simple after stepping away and looking logically what I needed. See original code for edits.

Answer (score 2):

Or try using [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
td.forEach(function(td) {
   if(td.textContent == 'Error') {
       td.innerHTML = '<button class="yellow_stoplight">' + 'Error' + '</button>';
   } 
  ...
}
```